# How to create matrix from a csv file with element labels base on column name?

Tags: r

I have one csv file with following data

```
Territory_Code  Region_Code Zone_Code   Product LOB     CFY_Apr_AOPB_Qty
565 10049   30001   CLIPPER                 1       1000
579 10054   30002   ABACIN                  1       2000
427 10017   30003   BUDGET                  1       3000
353 10041   30001   AVTAAR                  1       4000
115 10005   30002   KHAZANA                 5       5000
478 10093   30003   RONALDO                 1       6000
324 10036   30001   APEX - 50               1       7000
235 10042   30002   AVTAAR                  1       8000
```

I upload this file using

```
fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),
```

I Get data with all columns properly using data().
But i want to create matrix base on zone and product with example given below.

```
         CLIPPER ABACIN BUDGET AVTAAR KHAZANA RONALDO APEX-50 AVTAAR
30001    1000    0      0      4000   0       0       7000    0
30002    0       2000   0      0      5000    0       0       8000
30003    0       0      3000   0      0       6000    0       0
```

I'm using below code but i didn;t get proper output.

```
mat <- matrix(data()[, c("CFY_Apr_AOPB_Qty)], nrow = 10, ncol = 10, dimnames = list(data()[,c("zone"),c("product")]))
    print(mat)
```